# vb.net double data in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I did successfully show the data in `datagridview(dgvLogs)` but when i clicked again the button it double the data counts in my `Toolstripstatuslabelcountdata` that suppose to be remain only. Any suggestions?

```
 Private Sub btnShowData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowData.Click

 Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tblStudents"
            Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            Dim dataadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)

            Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
            connection.Open()
            dataadapter.Fill(ds, "tblStudents")
            connection.Close()
            dgvLogs.DataSource = ds
            dgvLogs.DataMember = "tblStudents"
            ToolStripStatusLabelCountData.Text = dgvLogs.RowCount.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: ds stands for dataset

Comment: Try reinit the `ds` object first: `ds = New DataSet()` right before filling it... IMHO, you don't need to fill a `DataSet`, you only need a `DataTable`, why don't you fill the `dbDataSet` object and then use that?

Comment: it works! i remove ds as public and join then in the private


dim ds as new DataSet, and remove DataTable in it. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### try this

ToolStripStatusLabelCountData.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString()

Comment: still the same when click again the button. anyway, thanks!